# need to access subclass property from superclass property

Tags: ios, swift, casting, codable, decodable

I need to pass models of type decodable and access title and subtitle from it so because Decodable doesn't have title and subtitle properties I implemented an extension for decodable and added a title and subtitle properties to Decodable So any object of type Decodable could write decodableObject.title so when I pass object which conform to decodable and contains title and subtitle properties I need then to access the data of it not Docodable object data but what happens that it just access Decodable extension properties so to access my target object I should make downcasting to this class which then I should write implementation for each model type

```
//decalring struct which conforms to Decodable 
struct TestModel:Decodable {
    var title:String?
}
//added property 
extension Decodable {
    var title:String?{
        return "Decodable base"
    }
}

func setup(){
        var testModel = TestModel()
        testModel.title = "Subclass"
        checkProperties(model: testModel, mod: TestModel.self)
    }

    func checkProperties<T:Decodable>(model:Any,mod:T.Type){
        typealias MMM = T
        let title = (model as! MMM).title
        print("type is \(title)")
    }
// the resutl will be "Type is Decodable Base"
```

I need the expected result to be 
// the result will be "Type is subclass"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, maybe this helps you:

```
protocol HasTitle {
  var title: String? { get }
}

extension Decodable {
  var title:String? {
    return "Decodable base"
  }
}

struct TestModel: Decodable, HasTitle {
  var title: String?
}

func checkProperties<T:HasTitle>(model:Any,mod:T.Type){
  typealias MMM = T
  let title = (model as! MMM).title
  print("type is \(title)")
}
```

**EDIT**

This makes usage of a concept called Retroactive Modeling. The rationale is separating that property in a protocol, which I called `HasTitle`. The trick is making an extension to `Decodable` which has a property `title` declared the same way you expect in `HasTitle` protocol. Then, whichever type who conforms to `Decodable` got that `title` property by default and you need just to declare `HasTitle` conformance. However, you're still free to override it `title` property.

Comment: Thanks, Your answer helped me a lot